# VBA Variables Dim issue

Tags: vba, excel, methods

Just a quick question on VBA

I am learning class modules in VBA and i have met a new practice of declaring variables inside class modules. Here it goes:

```
Public WithEvents TxtGroup As MSForms.TextBox
```

also

```
Dim Word1 As Word.Application

Dim bottomLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

Here after the the **As** and the **New** keywords instead of seeing a data type or an object or a reference to a class object we see  two words joined by a period just like some sort of directory...
e.g. *MSForms.TextBox* since my question is a bit of out-of-the-box i couldn't locate on my VBA books an ample explanation for this transition in the declaration technique. 
I need to learn classes really fast and i would definitely like to ask why do i meet this practice since i have never seen it in a module.

I have seen examples as

```
Private Sub xlApp_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
Dim wks As Worksheet
With Wb
For Each wks In .Worksheets
wks.PageSetup.LeftFooter = “Created by: “ & .Application.UserName
wks.PageSetup.RightFooter = Now
Next wks
End With
End Sub
```

Why these code blocks have no namespaces in their declarations while others have?
**thanks for watching my question**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [MSDN article about Namespaces in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx).

In conjunction with programming the term [**namespace** means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) means package:

> A namespace is a container for a set of identifiers (also known as
>   symbols, names).[1][2] Namespaces provide a level of indirection to
>   specific identifiers, thus making it possible to distinguish between
>   identifiers with the same exact name.

So a [**namespace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) enables [classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29) with the same name to co-exist and be used side-by-side. In every package one or more classes with a **unique** name can reside. For example:

For example:

```
namespace Teachers
    class Person end class
end namespace

namespace Doctors
    class Person end class
end namespace
```

In order to create a politician object you need to uniquely identify the class, so you can't just write:

```
Dim p as Person
```

because the compiler can't know which from the two Person classes to instantiate. That is why you identify the class with it's namespace:

```
Dim t as Teachers.Person
Dim d as Doctors.Person
```

In the example given by you:

```
Dim Word1 As Word.Application
```

**Word** is the **namespace**, Application the class and thus the type of the variable!

When defining a variable, the last part (after the last dot) is always a class, everything before the last dot is a namespace! In the example given by you, you are using the TextBox from the Namespace [Systems.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If the class name is unique and even if it resides in any namespace, there is no need to write it, because the compiler can infer the correct name automatically.
In VB.NET there is the **import** keyword, with which you can *import* a namespace to your code in order to use the classes without qualifiying them with the namespace.

Comment: I didn't absolutely got the gist could you refer please to an example?  Which is the namespace here -->MSForms.TextBox?

Comment: If i type Dim Word1 as Word.Application which is the namespace here>?

Comment: Word is the namespace, Application the class and thus the type of the variable! When defining a variable, the last part (after the last dot) is always a class, everything before the last dot is a namespace! In the example given by you, you are using the TextBox from the Namespace [Systems.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i changed my question because i couldnt edit the comment

Comment: i have seen examples as this one up in the revised main question you can see code that is has no namespace in it's declarations

Comment: Also if it is possible could it be a VBA example as i am new to coding? :P

Comment: I have updated my answer and addressed your questions. I'll extend it more in a moment.

Comment: Fascinating! Finaly i have autosearched my VBA the namespace workd on my books and none is explaining the namespace axiom. Is it a term for all programming languages? because i can remember seeing it in XML. To dispel my demons can this be done to a regular module also, does the container play any role?

Comment: Yes, namespacing in programming is a general term, **same** for (AFAIK) all programming and markup (XML) languages. What do you mean with **container**?

Comment: Patsy can this type of declaration be done in any module in VBA? and not just class modules?

Comment: By container i mean a module...a container that contains code

Comment: i am not sure, you have to try this. modules in VBA are something like static classes ... so i presume yes. :)

Comment: Yes! it should be possible.

Comment: Sorry for that it was very peculiary to me because while i am learning VBA i never say a namespace being used and i thought this practice was only done in code that resides in class modules...but as you say it can also be done in a user-form module and in a regular module also.

Comment: Glad, that the answer helped!

Comment: @pasty ....Politicians and Person in the same namespace - bit of a far fetched example?!